# Values of "class" attribute implicitely expand for certain markup elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I'm experimenting with a third party library written on top of jQuery.

I noticed, for a number of their widgets, that when your source says, for example,

```
<div id="myWidgetInst" class="their-widget-class-0" ... </div>
```

Firebug shows that the resulting DOM element reads:

```
 <div id="myWidgetInst" class="their-widget-class-0 their-widget-class-1 ..." ... </div>
```

How do they do it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably jquery !

there's probably a function running adding classes to the elements

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand your question but when looking at the "regular" source of the website, this source doesn't show any modifications to the DOM that happened due to javascript modifications. Firebug does show these updates.

using jQuery, you can add/remove classes simply by using `.addClass("className")` or `.removeClass("className")` function on the element you want to modify

Comment: Thanks! I didn't mean THIS site, everything was occuring on my "site".

Answer (score 0):

They would add classes to the element with jQuery. For example, if the plugin's purpose was to hide all elements on the page (innovative and highly practical, I know), they could use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("*").addClass("my-widget-made-your-element-invisible");
});
```

With the CSS:

```css
.my-widget-made-your-element-invisible { display: none; }
```

---

The methods in which you can manipulate the `class` attribute in jQuery include the following:

```
$("#elem").addClass("a");       // adds the class "a" to elem
$("#elem").removeClass("a");    // removes the class "a" from elem
$("#elem").attr("class", "a");  // gives elem a complete class of "a"
$("#elem").attr("class", "");   // removes all classes from attribute
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe you're spot on, they must be running their own "onload" routine, or .ready in jQuery parlance. And it does solver another mystery: that "their-widget-class-0" in my snippet, I could not find it in their distribution. Now I believe it is only a "virtual" class to give them a hint what is it that they really need to use. Pretty neet IMHO!